# Charting library that does not need to use excanvas for IE6-8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts

Are there any charting libraries that fall back to VML instead of excanvas for IE6-8?

An additional requirement is the ability to combine line charts with a scatter chart (simply dots in the chart)  (so I can't use the google visualization api)

Lastly, if a javascript library is required, preferrably jquery based.

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) uses VML for IE but I believe its charting is fairly rudimentary.  You could extend it with your own charts fairly easily.  It is not reliant on jquery.

Answer (score 0):

would you check this http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.html

Comment: As I said, can't use google since it does not allow a combination of line chart + scatter (point) chart. Thx.